# How can I prevent page breaks from occuring inside the body of a function?

Tags: listings, page-breaking

Is it possible to tell the `listings` package not to insert page breaks inside the body of a function? For instance,

```
void foo()
    {
//  Do not insert page break here
    }

//But here is fine
```

An ideal solution let the braces create paragraphs. A long function may be broken at `if` or `for`.

```
void foo()
    {
    if(...)
        {
        }
    //Second best page-break
    }
//Best page-break
```

Comment: *A solution let the braces create paragraphs.* Are you referring to my answer below. What do you mean by that? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @jubobs If possible, one generally prefer to add page break between paragraphs rather than in the middle of the paragraph. In the case of code, the pagebreak should be after the largest possible block.

Comment: My approach already allows you to specify exactly where you want line breaks... I don't understand what more I could do. As stated above, you should add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to better explain what the problem is.

Comment: @jubobs I guess I need to parse the code blocks if I want it automated. (Use \write18 ...)

Comment: You're moving the goalpost, here; what you're asking now (an automated solution, with varying pagebreaking penalties within a listing) is significantly more complicated than the original question.

Comment: @jubobs Yes, The former were thought as more quick-and-dirty sulotion. Since you did not really liked such a simplistic automation I developed the idea further.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think an automated solution would be wise, because you would run into problems with functions that span multiple pages, but here is an ad-hoc solution.

You can invoke (within an "escape to LaTeX" in your listings) the two macros defined below, `\forbidpgbr` and `\allowpgbr`, to locally forbid/allow pagebreaks. Note that the change takes effect only on the line immediately following that on which either macro is invoked.

Here is an example (the code is taken from [`git/bisect.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/bisect.c)).

### Normal output

In the screenshot below, a page break occurs in the body of the function, which is not what you want.

[image]

### Output when `\forbidpgbr` is used

However, by invoking `\forbidpgbr` on the line preceding the function's signature, you can prevent page breaks from occuring inside the body of the function. In case your listing contains multiple functions, you should also invoke `\allowpgbr` on the last line of each function.

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\makeatletter

\newif\ifpgbrallowed
\newcommand\allowpgbr
  {\global\pgbrallowedtrue}
\newcommand\forbidpgbr
  {\global\pgbrallowedfalse}

\lst@AddToHook{PreInit}{\allowpgbr}

\lst@AddToHook{EveryLine}{%
  \ifpgbrallowed%
  \else
    \nopagebreak%
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  numbers=left,
  escapechar=`,
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{lstlisting}
/*
 * This is a truly stupid algorithm, but it's only
 * used for bisection, and we just don't care enough.
 *
 * We care just barely enough to avoid recursing for
 * non-merge entries.
 */`\forbidpgbr`
static int count_distance(struct commit_list *entry)
{
    int nr = 0;

    while (entry) {
        struct commit *commit = entry->item;
        struct commit_list *p;

        if (commit->object.flags & (UNINTERESTING | COUNTED)
            break;
        if (!(commit->object.flags & TREESAME))
            nr++;
        commit->object.flags |= COUNTED;
        p = commit->parents;
        entry = p;
        if (p) {
            p = p->next;
            while (p) {
                nr += count_distance(p);
                p = p->next;
            }
        }
    }

    return nr;
}`\allowpgbr`
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```