# "Allow page break before the next line" inside lstlisting

Tags: listings, line-breaking, page-breaking

I am trying to use the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201014/2113) to have precise control over where page breaks can occur inside listings. My problem is twofold: it seems I can't put the commands on their own line, and also their effect seems to be off by one line.

Let me demonstrate what I mean. In the following file, the listing looks like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
import Clash.Prelude
import qualified Data.List as L

showSS :: Vec 7 Bool -> String
showSS (a :> b :> c :> d :> e :> f :> g :> Nil) = unlines . L.concat $
    [ L.replicate 1 $ horiz   a
    , L.replicate 3 $ vert  f   b
    , L.replicate 1 $ horiz   g
    , L.replicate 3 $ vert  e   c
    , L.replicate 1 $ horiz   d
    ]
`\allowpgbr`
  where
    horiz True  = " ###### "
    horiz False = " ...... "

    vert b1 b2 = part b1 <> "      " <> part b2
      where
        part True  = "#"
        part False = "."
\end{lstlisting}
```

I would like this to result in a listing that can only have a page break right *before* the `where` line. But instead, I get an empty line before the `where` (I guess because in `` `\allowpgbr` `` I don't know how to also escape the end-of-line?), and then I get `where`, and *then* I get a page break:

[image]

So my question is, how can I change it so that there would be no empty line before `where`, and `where` would already be on the new page (if a page break is needed)?

Full code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset%
    { basicstyle=\ttfamily
    , escapeinside=``
    }

\newif\ifpgbrallowed
\newcommand\allowpgbr
  {\global\pgbrallowedtrue}
\newcommand\forbidpgbr
  {\global\pgbrallowedfalse}

\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{PreInit}{\forbidpgbr}

\lst@AddToHook{EveryLine}{%
  \ifpgbrallowed%
    \forbidpgbr%
  \else
    \nopagebreak%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{lstlisting}
import Clash.Prelude
import qualified Data.List as L

showSS :: Vec 7 Bool -> String
showSS (a :> b :> c :> d :> e :> f :> g :> Nil) = unlines . L.concat $
    [ L.replicate 1 $ horiz   a
    , L.replicate 3 $ vert  f   b
    , L.replicate 1 $ horiz   g
    , L.replicate 3 $ vert  e   c
    , L.replicate 1 $ horiz   d
    ]
`\allowpgbr`
  where
    horiz True  = " ###### "
    horiz False = " ...... "

    vert b1 b2 = part b1 <> "      " <> part b2
      where
        part True  = "#"
        part False = "."
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know yet how to avoid the empty line, but at least I figured out that the way to fix the off-by-one error is to move the optional line break callback from `EveryLine` to `EOL`:

```
\lst@AddToHook{EOL}{%
  \ifpgbrallowed%
    \forbidpgbr%
  \else
    \nopagebreak%
  \fi
}
```